# Adding space between bars in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'd like to add spaces between bars in ggplot2. This page offers one solution: http://www.streamreader.org/stats/questions/6204/how-to-increase-the-space-between-the-bars-in-a-bar-plot-in-ggplot2. Instead of using factor levels for the x-axis groupings, however, this solution creates a numeric sequence, x.seq, to manually place the bars and then scales them using the `width()` argument. `width()` doesn't work, however, when I use factor level groupings for the x-axis as in the example, below.

```
library(ggplot2)

Treatment <- rep(c('T','C'),each=2)
Gender <- rep(c('M','F'),2)
Response <- sample(1:100,4)
df <- data.frame(Treatment, Gender, Response)

hist <- ggplot(df, aes(x=Gender, y=Response, fill=Treatment, stat="identity"))
hist + geom_bar(position = "dodge") + scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 
    100), name = "")
```

Does anyone know how to get the same effect as in the linked example,  but while using factor level groupings?

Comment: Also of note is the usefulness of facetting `+ facet_grid(~Treatment)`

Answer (score 96, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
hist + geom_bar(width=0.4, position = position_dodge(width=0.5))
```

- `width` in `geom_bar` determines the width of the bar.
- `width` in `position_dodge` determines the position of each bar.

Probably you can easily understand their behavior after you play with them for a while.

[image]

Comment: `width` in `geom_histogram()` is deprecated in modern ggplot2 (>= 2.1.0).

Comment: what if I want to keep the bars per-group together (e.g. the 'C' and 'T' bars here) but want to change the spacing between groups ('M' and 'F' here)?

Comment: Regarding the question by user5359531, see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51892875/how-to-increase-the-space-between-grouped-bars-in-ggplot2

Comment: As kohske didn't describe how they work: `width` in `geom_bar` is the width of x-axis bar groups. `width` in `position_dodge` is the width of bars within each x-axis group. A width of "1" means that bars/groups touch each other. Widths < 1 adds space between bars or between groups.