# RCurl or XML Challenge: Read Pastebin into R

Tags: r

Flex your RCurl/XML muscle. Shortest code wins. Parse into R: http://pastebin.com/CDzYXNbG

Data should be:

```
structure(list(Treatment = structure(c(2L, 2L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("C", 
"T"), class = "factor"), Gender = c("M", "F", "M", "F"), Response = c(56L, 
58L, 6L, 63L)), .Names = c("Treatment", "Gender", "Response"), row.names = c(NA, 
-4L), class = "data.frame")
```

Good luck!

Note: dummy data kindly provided by this question: [Adding space between bars in ggplot2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6085238/adding-space-between-bars-in-ggplot2)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Same idea as kohske but slightly shorter and more clear I think

```
library(XML)
eval(parse(text=gsub('\r\n','\n',xpathApply(htmlTreeParse('http://pastebin.com/CDzYXNbG',useInternal=T),'//textarea',xmlValue))))
```

Comment: So far, looks like you're in the lead as this pulls in the dataframe without other characters and allows one to easily assign to a variable.

Comment: Chosen for being the shortest code using the specified page. Congratz!

Answer (score 4):

RCurl is not necessary for my code, since XML packages can parse URL for file argument.

Please execute

```
library(XML)
```

before the examples below.

Code 1 is **oneliner**:

```
eval(parse(text=htmlTreeParse("http://pastebin.com/CDzYXNbG",handlers=(function(){qt <- NULL;list(textarea=function(node,...){qt<<-gsub("[\r\n]", "", unclass(node$children$text)$value);node},.qt=function()qt)})())$.qt()))
```

Code 2 is shorter, but I think this is not shortest.

```
htmlTreeParse("http://pastebin.com/CDzYXNbG",h=list(textarea=function(n)z<<-gsub("[\r\n]","",unclass(n$c$t)$v)));eval(parse(text=z))
```

As this question is a kind of game, please decrypt this code.

**UPDATED**

After looking at @JD Long's excellent solution, here is a shortest code:

```
eval(parse(file(sub("m/","m/raw.php?i=","http://pastebin.com/CDzYXNbG"))))
```

Now question is how to make a desired url string in the shortest code ;-p

Updated again. This is shorter by some characters.

```
source(sub("m/","m/raw.php?i=","http://pastebin.com/CDzYXNbG"))$va
```

Comment: Code 1 works as intended. Code 2 cannot be assigned to a variable. Good try though!

Comment: You can assign in Code 2. Please carefully look into the code.

Comment: Technically the shortest, but does not use the page specified.

Answer (score 4):

You guys are making this way too hard:

`eval(parse(file("http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=CDzYXNbG")))`

OK, so I cheated. But starting from the same URL you could get the same end:

`eval(parse(file(paste("http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=", strsplit("http://pastebin.com/CDzYXNbG", "/")[[1]][4], sep=""))))`

Which still puts me in the lead :)

Comment: Technically short, but does not use the page specified.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not perfectly sure what you are trying to achieve here, but maybe does what you ask for (not using any fancy packages, just regex):

```
fullText<-(paste(readLines("http://pastebin.com/CDzYXNbG"), collapse="\n"))
regexp<-"<textarea[^>]*id=\"paste_code\"[^>]*>(.*)</textarea>"
txtarpos<-regexpr(regexp, fullText)
txtarstrt<-txtarpos[1]
txtarlen<-unlist(attributes(txtarpos)["match.length"])
txtarstp<-txtarstrt+txtarlen
txtarpart<-substr(fullText, txtarpos[1], txtarstp)
retval<-gsub("\n", "", gsub("&quot;", "\"", gsub(regexp, "\\1", txtarpart), fixed=TRUE), fixed=TRUE)
cat(retval)
```

I'm also pretty sure this can be improved upon somewhat, but it does the job I think you asked for. Even if doesn't: thanks for making me want to refresh my regex basics!

Comment: `Error: unexpected input in "retval<-gsub("\n", "", gsub("&quot;", "\"", gsub(regexp, "\\1", txtarpart), fixed=TRUE), fixed=TRUE)\"` Interesting use of pure regex!