# How to increase the space between the bars in a bar plot in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

How can I increase the space between the bars in a bar plot in [ggplot2](http://had.co.nz/ggplot2/) ?

Comment: could you please provide code example illustrating your problem? In my experience the defaults of ggplot2 are really good, so there should be a good reason to change them.

Comment: Maybe of interest for your specific question? :)

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6085238/adding-space-between-bars-in-ggplot2

Answer (score 80, accepted):

You can always play with the `width` parameter, as shown below:

```
df <- data.frame(x=factor(LETTERS[1:4]), y=sample(1:100, 4))
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data=df, aes(x=x, y=y, width=.5)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity", position="identity") +
  opts(title="width = .5") + labs(x="", y="") +
  theme_bw()
```

Compare with the following other settings for `width`:

[image]

So far, so good. Now, suppose we have two factors. In case you would like to play with evenly spaced juxtaposed bars (like when using `space` together with `beside=TRUE` in `barplot()`), it's not so easy using `geom_bar(position="dodge")`: you can change bar width, but not add space in between adjacent bars (and I didn't find a convenient solution on Google). I ended up with something like that:

```
df <- data.frame(g=gl(2, 1, labels=letters[1:2]), y=sample(1:100, 4))
x.seq <- c(1,2,4,5)
ggplot(data=transform(df, x=x.seq), aes(x=x, y=y, width=.85)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity", aes(fill=g)) + labs(x="", y="") + 
  scale_x_discrete(breaks = NA) + 
  geom_text(aes(x=c(sum(x.seq[1:2])/2, sum(x.seq[3:4])/2), y=0, 
                label=c("X","Y")), vjust=1.2, size=8)
```

The vector used for the $x$-axis is "injected" in the data.frame, so that so you change the outer spacing if you want, while `width` allows to control for inner spacing. Labels for the $x$-axis might be enhanced by using `scale_x_discrete()`.

[image]

Comment: Apparently, `opts` is no longer existing in R 4.0 and above.

Comment: As of ggplot 3.0.0, you can use `position_dodge2`. It takes a `padding` argument that adds space in between the bars. See my answer below.

Answer (score 61):

For space between factor bars use

```
ggplot(data = d, aes(x=X, y=Y, fill=F)) 
 + geom_bar(width = 0.8, position = position_dodge(width = 0.9))
```

The width in geom_bar controls the bar width in relation to the x-axis while the width in position_dodge control the width of the space given to both bars also in relation to the x-axis. Play around with the width to find one that you like.

Answer (score 3):

Thank you very much chl.! I had the same problem and you helped me solving it. Instead of using geom_text to add the X-labels I used scale_x_continuous (see below)

```
geom_text(aes(x=c(sum(x.seq[1:2])/2, sum(x.seq[3:4])/2), y=0, 
            label=c("X","Y")), vjust=1.2, size=8)
```

replaced by

```
scale_x_continuous(breaks=c(mean(x.seq[1:2]), mean(x.seq[3:4])), labels=c("X", "Y"))
```

Answer (score 3):

As of [ggplot 3.0.0](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/releases?page=2), you can use `position_dodge2`. It takes a `padding` argument that adds space in between the bars.

```
library(ggplot2) # version >= 3.0.0
set.seed(1530676800) # 
tib <- tibble(
  group=rep(LETTERS[1:4], each=3), 
  subgroup=rep(letters[24:26], 4),
  y=sample(1:100, 4*3)
)
ggplot(tib, aes(x=group, fill=subgroup, y=y)) + 
  geom_col(position=position_dodge2())
```

[image: ggplot2 geom_col with position_dodge2 default padding]

Default padding is 0.1. Since I know you want to see different padding options:

```
library(purrr)
library(cowplot)
theme_set(theme_cowplot())

n_col <- 2
bottom_row_starts <- 3
plots0 <- purrr::imap(0.1*c(1:4), \(pad, idx) {
  ret <- ggplot(tib, aes(x=group, fill=subgroup, y=y)) + 
    geom_col(position=position_dodge2(padding=pad)) +
    labs(subtitle=paste0("Padding = ", pad)) #+
    #theme(plot.margin = margin(6, 0, 6, 0))
  if (bottom_row_starts > idx) {
    ret <- ret + xlab(NULL)
  }
  if(1 != (idx %% n_col)) {
    ret <- ret + ylab(NULL)
  }
  return(ret)
})
leg <- cowplot::get_legend(plots0[[1]])

plots <- plots0 %>% purrr::map(\(pp) {
  pp + theme(legend.position="none")
})

cowplot::plot_grid(
  plotlist=plots,
  ncol=n_col
) %>% cowplot::plot_grid(
  leg, 
  rel_widths = c(4, 1)
)
```

[image: ggplot2 geom_col with position_dodge2 varied padding arranged with cowplot plot_grid]

Answer (score 1):

For space between POSIXlt bars you need adjust the width from the number of seconds in a day

```
# POSIXlt example: full & half width
d <- data.frame(dates = strptime(paste(2016, "01", 1:10, sep = "-"), "%Y-%m-%d"),
            values = 1:10)

ggplot(d, aes(dates, values)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", width = 60*60*24) 

ggplot(d, aes(dates, values)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", width = 60*60*24*0.5)
```