# Space between every X bars in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

Coming from this example:

```
df <- data.frame(TYPE = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"), VALUE = c(10, 11, 9, 12, 10, 8))
ggplot(df, aes(x = TYPE, y = VALUE)) + geom_bar(stat = "identity")
```

Is it possible to add a space in a bar chart after every X bars? In this code maybe after every second bar (so that there is a space between B/C and D/E, but not between the others).

Threads I found on SO focused on adding spaces between all bars.

[Adding space between bars in ggplot2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6085238/adding-space-between-bars-in-ggplot2)

[How to increase the space between the bars in a bar plot in ggplot2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12040245/how-to-increase-the-space-between-the-bars-in-a-bar-plot-in-ggplot2/12040246)

Comment: 1) Shouldn't it be a space between B/C and *D/E*? 2) Maybe it will makee the question more complete if you edit it with links to the threads you have found on SO.

Comment: 1) You are right, thank you. 2) I added the threads.