# R - how to increase the space between bars in bar plot in ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a bar plot with ~140 groups on the y-axis, and each name is jumbled together in the plots previewer.

I used [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12040245/how-to-increase-the-space-between-the-bars-in-a-bar-plot-in-ggplot2), but the space won't change.

I have been using the geom_col code below to try and separate them, but the names still are jumbled (even after trying 2000 for the position_dodge).

```
 geom_col(width = 3, position = position_dodge(40))
```

Is there another code within ggplot or r that I can use to separate the names? I added a picture of my plot below.

[Screengrab of part of my cbar plot to show the overlap of names](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ko01Q.png)

Comment: You have a 140 labels, that is a lot of information to attempt to displace.  First thing is try to reduce the font size of the labels that will help some, but most likely you will need to reduce the number of labels to make a readable axis.

Comment: I think it would take a font size of under 6pt to fit 140 labels on a page, or maybe you could get to 10pt if you offset every other label, but still that’s going to be hard to read for anyone.

Comment: The plot preview pane has a limited height, depending on how big you make it on the Studio IDE. If you make it longer, the plot will look somewhat nicer. But the real question is how you intend to make space for 140 lines of text. An option would be saving the plot into an image file that's very long and see how it looks, like this: `ggsave("plot.jpg", width = 15, height = 40, units = "cm")`

Comment: Thank you everyone! I decreased the font size and it was able to fit everything in if I maxed out the preview height.