# Different space between bars geom_bar

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-bar

I tried my best to read related questions to my issue. The most relevant was: [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6085238/adding-space-between-bars-in-ggplot2). However I was not able to figure out how to solve my issue. I had a dataset like

```
   structure(list(COMPANY = structure(1:5, .Label = c("Architecten", 
" 2.0", " Adema", "B.V.", 
" Alex"), class = "factor"), `YOUR COMPANY PERFORMANCE ORIENTATION` = c(5, 
7, 6, 4.5, 4.5), `AVERAGE PERFORMANCE ORIENTATION` = c(5.17, 
5.17, 5.17, 5.17, 5.17), `YOUR COMPANY LEARNING ORIENTATION` = c(5, 
5.6, 5.8, 6.2, 3.8), `AVERAGE LEARNING ORIENTATION` = c(5.67, 5.67, 5.67, 5.67, 5.67)), .Names = c("COMPANY", "YOUR COMPANY PERFORMANCE ORIENTATION", 
"AVERAGE PERFORMANCE ORIENTATION", "YOUR COMPANY LEARNING ORIENTATION", 
"AVERAGE LEARNING ORIENTATION"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
5L))
```

By using melt (from library reshape2) I was able to obtain:

```
structure(list(COMPANY = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 
+ 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L), class = "factor", .Label = c("Architecten", 
" 2.0", " Adema", "B.V.", 
" Alex")), variable = structure(c(1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L), .Label = c("YOUR COMPANY PERFORMANCE ORIENTATION", "AVERAGE PERFORMANCE ORIENTATION", 
"YOUR COMPANY LEARNING ORIENTATION", "AVERAGE LEARNING ORIENTATION"
), class = "factor"), value = c(5, 7, 6, 4.5, 4.5, 5.17, 5.17, 
5.17, 5.17, 5.17, 5, 5.6, 5.8, 6.2, 3.8, 5.67, 5.67, 5.67, 5.67, 
5.67)), .Names = c("COMPANY", "variable", "value"), row.names = c(NA, 
-20L), class = "data.frame")
```

By using the following code, I was able to plot the average and company variables side by side:

```
plot_try <-ggplot(mydataset,aes(COMPANY,value,fill=variable))+
geom_bar(stat="identity",position="dodge")+ theme(axis.ticks = element_blank(), axis.text.x = element_blank())+ facet_wrap(~COMPANY)
```

i want to add space between the first two bars ("your company performance orientation" and "average performance orientation") and the last 2 bars, but I am not able to do that. Any suggestion on what to add to my code? Thanks.

Comment: +1 for posting your first R question with an easily reproducible example together with the code you have tried. Cheers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use your melted dataframe `mydataset` and add new variable that contains grouping number for each two bars you need to combine. Then use this new variable for the x values.

```
mydataset$group<-rep(c(1,2),each=10)
#as suggested by @Henrik more general solution
mydataset$group <- grepl("LEARNING", mydataset$variable)

ggplot(mydataset,aes(group,value,fill=variable))+
  geom_bar(stat="identity",position="dodge")+ 
  theme(axis.ticks = element_blank(), axis.text.x = element_blank())+ 
  facet_wrap(~COMPANY)
```

[image]

Comment: Nice! +1! Perhaps `mydataset$group <- grepl("LEARNING", mydataset$variable)` makes it slightly more general?

Comment: @Henrik Thanks, that really would be more general

Comment: I'm really grateful. both answers have been illuminating for me. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This does not directly answer your question about space between the bars, but provides another way to think about presenting your data. Assuming `df` has your original data (before `melt(...)`).

```
gg <- reshape(df,idvar="COMPANY",
              varying=list(c(2,4),c(3,5)), v.names=c("Individual","Average"),
              timevar="Metric", times=c("Performance","Learning"),
              direction="long")

ggplot(gg)+
  geom_point(aes(x=COMPANY,y=Individual))+
  geom_hline(aes(yintercept=Average))+
  geom_linerange(aes(x=COMPANY,ymin=Average,ymax=Individual,
                     color=factor(sign(Individual-Average))))+
  facet_grid(~Metric) +
  labs(x="",y="Scores") +
  theme(legend.position="none",
        axis.text.x=element_text(angle=90, vjust=0.4, hjust=1, size=15, face="bold"))
```

Produces this:
[image]

Comment: Thanks. This is really interesting. I need to play a bit with it in order to see how to make it suitable to produce single company reports. Thanks a lot.