# Adding Space between my geom_histogram bars-not barplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

Let's say I want to make a histogram

So I use the following code

```
v100<-c(runif(100))

v100
library(ggplot2)
private_plot<-ggplot()+aes(v100)+geom_histogram(binwidth = (0.1),boundary=0
)+scale_x_continuous(breaks=seq(0,1,0.1), lim=c(0,1))
private_plot
```

[image: plot]

How do I separate my columns so that the whole thing is more pleasing to the eye?

I tried this but it somehow doesn't work:

[Adding space between bars in ggplot2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6085238/adding-space-between-bars-in-ggplot2)

Thanks

Comment: I want a histogram

Comment: see i have an actual histogram with many colums of the same height. They look like one grey blob.

Comment: I am not sure what you want, but histograms dont have spaces. https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/56122/why-do-histograms-not-have-spaces-in-between-bars-as-opposed-to-a-bar-graph

Comment: You probably want to add more bins: `ggplot()+aes(v100)+geom_histogram(bins=50)+scale_x_continuous(breaks=seq(0,1,0.1), lim=c(0,1))`

Comment: this is no duplicate to the other question(barplot). My question is about histograms.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You could set the **line color** of the histogram bars with the `col` parameter, and the **filling color** with the `fill` parameter. This is not really adding space between the bars, but it makes them visually distinct.

```
library(ggplot2)
set.seed(9876)
v100<-c(runif(100))

### use "col="grey" to set the line color
ggplot() +
  aes(v100) +
  geom_histogram(binwidth = 0.1, fill="black", col="grey") +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(0,1,0.1), lim = c(0,1))
```

Yielding this graph:

[image]

Please let me know whether this is what you want.

Comment: Definitely, not related with the tittle of the question

Answer (score 8):

If you want to increase the *space* for e.g. to indicate that values are discrete, one thing to do is to plot your histogram as a bar plot. In that case, you have to summarize the data yourself, and use `geom_col()` instead of `geom_histogram()`. If you want to increase the space further, you can use the `width` parameter.

```
library(tidyverse)
lambda <- 1:6

pois_bar <- 
    map(lambda, ~rpois(1e5, .x)) %>% 
    set_names(lambda) %>% 
    as_tibble() %>% 
    gather(lambda, value, convert = TRUE) %>% 
    count(lambda, value)

pois_bar %>% 
    ggplot() +
    aes(x = value, y = n) +
    geom_col(width = .5) +
    facet_wrap(~lambda, scales = "free", labeller = "label_both")
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Just use `color` and `fill` options to distinguish between the body and border of bins:

```
library(ggplot2)
set.seed(1234)
df <- data.frame(sex=factor(rep(c("F", "M"), each=200)),
                 weight=round(c(rnorm(200, mean=55, sd=5), rnorm(200, mean=65, sd=5))))

ggplot(df, aes(x=weight)) + 
geom_histogram(color="black", fill="white")
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

In cases where you are creating a "histogram" over a range of integers, you could use:

```
ggplot(data) + geom_bar(aes(x = value, y = ..count..))
```

Answer (score 1):

I just came across this issue. My solution was to add vertical lines at the points separating my bins. I use "theme_classic" and have a white background. I set my bins to break at 10, 20, 30, etc. So I just added 9 vertical lines with:

```
geom_vline(xintercept=10, linetype="solid", color = "white", size=2)+
geom_vline(xintercept=20, linetype="solid", color = "white", size=2)+
etc
```

A silly hack, but it works.