# ggplot: Modify histogram plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram, viridis

I made this plot using the following code:

```
ggplot(all, aes(x = year, color = layer)) +
  geom_histogram(binwidth = 0.5, fill = "white", alpha = 0.5, position = "dodge") +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = pretty(all$year)) +
  scale_color_discrete(name = "title", labels = c("A","B")) +
  theme_light() +
  theme(panel.grid.minor = element_blank(), panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
        text = element_text(size = 20),
        axis.title.x = element_text(margin = margin(t = 25, r = 0, b = 0, l = 0)),
        axis.title.y = element_text(margin = margin(t = 0, r = 25, b = 0, l = 0)),
        axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 50, hjust = 1, size = 18, color = "black"),
        axis.text.y = element_text(size = 18, color = "black"))
```

I would now like to change the colors first, using colors from the viridis palette. Furthermore, there are blue and red strokes between the histograms, which I would like to remove.
Could someone help me to change the code?
Thanks in advance!

Test Data:

```
year <- runif(10, 2014, 2021)
year <- round(year, 0)
layer <- sample(c("A","B"), size=10, replace=T)
all <- as.data.frame(year,layer)
```

[image]

Comment: could you provide `dput(all)`?

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer, I created some test data.

Comment: you could set `binwidth=1` to avoid the empty bins.

Comment: Is there another way to increase the space between the years?

Comment: perhaps have a look at : https://stackoverflow.com/a/58155387/13513328

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you want a bar plot not a histogram.

```
all <- data.frame(year,layer) ## fix the sample data creation

ggplot(all, aes(x = year, fill = layer)) +  ## I think fill looks better...
  geom_bar(position = position_dodge(preserve = "single")) +  ## bar, not histogram
  #scale_x_continuous(breaks = pretty(all$year)) + ## this line just confirmed defaults
  scale_fill_viridis_d() +
  theme_light() ## omitted the rest of the theme as irrelevant for the issue at hand
```

[image]

If you do want outline color, not fill, switching to `geom_bar` "fixes" the strokes between the bars:

```
ggplot(all, aes(x = year, color = layer)) +
  geom_bar(position = position_dodge(preserve = "single"), fill = NA) +
  scale_color_viridis_d() +
  theme_light()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, this is helpful information!

Comment: You dont need to answer. Just accept the solution.