# How to increase spaces between categories in ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I aim to increase the space between all the categories on the x-axis. For example, the estimate -173.22 extends to the side of Italy. If i increase the space between the categories then i make sure the estimate texts don't overlap. Another way to do it is to decrease the size of the text, but i would like to keep it as it is.

The only related questions on StackOverflow are with `geom_bar` or `geom_col`: [Adding space between bars in ggplot2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6085238/adding-space-between-bars-in-ggplot2). But they don't seem to solve the problem. Could someone help with it please?

[image]

Here is the data and the code:

```
df= structure(list(cntry = structure(1:3, .Label = c("France", "Italy", 
                                                 "United Kingdom"), class = "factor"), term = c("unemp", "unemp", "unemp"), 
               estimate = c(-173.22, 202.12, 508.44
               )), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = "data.frame")

df %>%
  mutate(label = replace(round(estimate, 2),cntry==1, '')) %>%
  ggplot(aes(estimate, cntry,label=label)) + 
  geom_text(hjust= -0.2, size= 10)  + 
  geom_point(mapping=aes(x=estimate, y=cntry), size=5) +
  coord_flip()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can control how much padding is added on the sides of France and UK with:

```
scale_y_discrete(expand = expansion(add = .2)) +
```

or if you want more padding on the UK side:

```
scale_y_discrete(expand = expansion(add = c(.2, 0.5))) +
```

[image]